# Get width and height of image with ng2-file-upload

Tags: angular, ng2-file-upload

I want to get and check the width and height of an uploaded image using ng2-file-upload and Angular 6.

My code so far is:

```
constructor() {
    this.uploader = this.initializeUploader("url");
}

public uploader;


private initializeUploader(url: string): FileUploader {
    const uploadOptions: FileUploaderOptions = {
        allowedMimeType: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png' ],

    }
    const uploader = new FileUploader(uploadOptions);

    uploader.onAfterAddingFile = item => {
        console.log(item);
        //Want to get width here
    }

    return uploader;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
```

I was looking for solutions but nothing worked for me. Found the idea to use

```
Upload.imageDimensions(file).then()
```

[here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/568). But i don't understand how/where to import 'Upload'. Also found the solution to add

```
ngf-min-height="1"
```

in the input-element but i can't find where i can "catch" the error, if the size of the input image is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform your file to a base64, and create an image with that base as the source. During the `load` hook, you can get the size of the image. Here is a working snippet !

```js
function change() {
  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  const file = input.files[0];
  
  getBase64(file).then(base64 => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => console.log(img.width, img.height);
    img.src = base64;
  });
}

function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="change()">
```

Comment: I get for 'function': Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. 
So i changed it to 'public'. also i put a "this" in front of getBase64(... so i have this.getBase64(...

in the line img.src = base64 i get the error: "[ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'." Dont know how to solve this. if i comment it out, the code runs but does not output the width and height

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got this working with some changes of the post of trichetriche:

```
    public change() {
    const input = document.querySelector('input');
    const file = input.files[0];

    this.getBase64(file).then(base64 => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => console.log(img.width, img.height);
      img.src = base64.toString();
    });
  }

  public getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
  }
```

and html:

```
 <input type="file" (change)="change()">
```